# Problems with dupes in list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having this weird problem with setting a list with Angular.

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
```

What  I'm trying to do is fetching som data from an api with $http and set the source after I parse it:

```
var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.Items = jdata;
console.log(jdata);
```

The above code produces the above error. I've tried to add `track by $index` but that bugs the list and I get XX elements that makes no sence (its just three).

If I take the data fom the console output and set Items equals that, it works fine!

```
$scope.Items = [{ "Id": 1, "OrganizationId": 1,... }];
```

So what could the problem be? only when I get the data from the server (ASP.NET Web API) that I get the problem. And If I paste the outputted data from the console output and use it... it works just fine!

My markup:

```
           <div ng-repeat="item in Items">
                <p>{{item.Content}}</p>
                <p>{{item.State}}</p>
                <button ng-click="UnCompleteItem(item.Id)">UnComplete</button>
                <button ng-click="CompleteItem(item.Id)">Complete</button>
            </div>
```

My data (`console.log(jdata)`), 3 items:

```
[{"Id":1,"OrganizationId":1,"Content":"Item1","State":1,"CreatedBy":1,"CreatedDate":"2015-02-28T10:25:24.208783+01:00","ModifyBy":0,"ModifyDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CompletedBy":0,"CompletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Id":2,"OrganizationId":1,"Content":"Item2","State":1,"CreatedBy":1,"CreatedDate":"2015-02-28T10:25:24.208783+01:00","ModifyBy":0,"ModifyDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CompletedBy":0,"CompletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Id":3,"OrganizationId":1,"Content":"Item3","State":1,"CreatedBy":1,"CreatedDate":"2015-02-28T10:25:24.208783+01:00","ModifyBy":0,"ModifyDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CompletedBy":0,"CompletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]
```

[Fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/noa4870v/)

**SOLUTION (????):**

Thanks to camden_kid I "figured" it out. I don't know why but parsing the string from the server 2 (!!!) times solves the problem. First time with JSON.parse then with angular.fromJson:

```
            var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
            var jdata2 = angular.fromJson(jdata) // could also use JSON.parse again

            $scope.Items = jdata2;
```

While console.log(jdata) looks like the array listed above, outputting jdata to looks like this:

`[Object, Object, Object]` in Chrome Console output, and it now works!!

I'm now able to set $scope.Items with the data from the $http and I don't need the `track by` part either!
I'm not happy with this solution, it seems very hacky so If anyone know why I have to do it this way I would be happy if you could let me know :D

Comment: @camden_kid yes, saw that site. 'track by $index' bugs the list. Adding a lot og bogus data :/

Comment: @camden_kid yes. If I take the data from console output and set the $scope.Items and drop the $http it works fine! :) I'm very confused :D Thank you for your time by the way!

Comment: @camden_kid by the way, should not 'track by item.Id' work too? As I have a Id in my data? If I do that it still throws dupe error, but it states 'item.Id&p1=undefined' so Im guessing it can't find Id?

Comment: @camden_kid if I do that I get an error, undefined is not a function... so it does not know what splice is because it does not understand that jdata is an array?

Comment: @camden_kid I still get dupes... adding  track by $index gives me 752 keys... all empty. I threw away the splice

Comment: What does **typeof jdata** return?

Comment: @camden_kid string... wow. Shouldnt JSON.parse(data) to the trick?

Comment: @Jason94 what's in the data then?

Comment: See my solution, parsing it two times - even with JSON.parse solves the problem!

Comment: @camden_kid add your solution of double parse and Ill accept it! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've added an answer but I'd like to come back to this question later to get a better solution. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with JSON parsing of **data**. It is returning a string rather than an object. The temporary solution is to parse again:

```
var jdata = JSON.parse(jdata);
```